# How to remove redundancy item in CardView layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I'm using a CardView Layout in a RecyclerView, JSON will load data and fill the adapter. My layout includes a ImageView, a TextView and everything is fine.

This is the **Adapter** class (**UPDATED**):

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 4;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    Context context;
    List<CarData> getCarData;  // getDataAdapter
    ImageLoader imageThumbLoader;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<CarData> getCarData, Context context){
        super();
        this.getCarData = getCarData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {
        // if (!isPositionHeader(position)) {
            CarData getCarData1 = getCarData.get(position - 1);
            imageThumbLoader = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

            imageThumbLoader.get(getCarData1.getImageThumb(),
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                            Viewholder.imageThumb,//Server Image
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                    )
            );

        Viewholder.imageThumb.setImageUrl(getCarData1.getImageThumb(), imageThumbLoader);
        Viewholder.titleName.setText(getCarData1.getTitleName());
        Viewholder.doorName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Số cửa:</b> " + getCarData1.getDoorName()));
        Viewholder.seatName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Số ghế:</b> " + getCarData1.getSeatName()));
        Viewholder.cityName.setText(Html.fromHtml(getCarData1.getCityName()));
        Viewholder.districtName.setText(Html.fromHtml(getCarData1.getDistrictName()));

        // }
    }

    public int getDataAdapter() {
        return getCarData == null ? 0 : getCarData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        }

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return getDataAdapter();  // + 1
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView titleName;
        public NetworkImageView imageThumb;
        public TextView doorName;
        public TextView seatName;
        public TextView cityName;
        public TextView districtName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            titleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleName);
            imageThumb = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageThumb);
            doorName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.doorName);
            seatName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.seatName);
            cityName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
            districtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.districtName);
        }
    }

}
```

My **layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
card_view:contentPadding="3dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageThumb"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Image View"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageThumb"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageThumb"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/doorName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seatName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cityName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/districtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="KIỂM TRA TÌNH TRẠNG XE"
        android:textColor="@color/color_primary_green_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_item32"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView_item32"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I load data for the first time, there is a redundant item. Look at the following attachment:

[image]

The exception has happened when updated code:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample, PID: 9794
              java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=18; index=-1
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
                  at pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.RecyclerViewAdapter$override.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:54)
                  at pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.RecyclerViewAdapter$override.access$dispatch(RecyclerViewAdapter.java)
                  at pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:0)
                  at pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:20)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
```

How do I remove this redundant item in the CardView?

Comment: setvisibility(GONE)

Comment: In my Activity, I have used it, but same the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have + 1 in your overridden `getItemCount()` method. It causes that you have one extra item in your list.

Then you have the method `isPositionHeader`, which you call in the `onBindViewHolder` method to find out, if the position is a header position. You are filling your `cardview` with data, if it is not the header position. But if it is the header position, you just skip it. So the first item, which is blank, is the header using the same cardview, as the other items, in fact.

Try to remove the + 1 and this condition `if (!isPositionHeader(position))`.

Comment: Hi @untosabla: Thank for your answer, I have remove +1 and condition: if (!isPositionHeader(position)). I think it can seem remove first item, but it has happened an error, you can review my code

Comment: @ThanNamPham sure, I'm sorry, I forgot that you need to remove ` - 1` from this line `CarData getCarData1 = getCarData.get(position - 1);` in your `onBindViewHolder` method.